# Get value from an generic record in avro 1.8.2

Tags: java, avro

I am trying to retrieve values of fields from a `GenericRecord` (`Avro 1.8.2`)

```
genericRecord.get(index) works but genericRecord.get(field_name) only gets me a null value.

        genericRecord =reader.read(null, decoder);
        ListIterator<Field> itr=  genericRecord.getSchema().getFields().listIterator(); 
        System.out.println("getting schema from generic record +" + genericRecord.getSchema());
        while(itr.hasNext())
        {   
            String nextField = itr.next().toString();
            System.out.println("field right now is :"+ nextField+" the value in the generic record is "+ genericRecord.get(nextField));
            binaryObjBuilder.setField(nextField, genericRecord.get(nextField));

        }
        for (int i=0;i<14;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("the values at index: "+i+" is "+ genericRecord.get(i));
        }
```

The output of the above snippet is

> getting schema from generic record +     {"type":"record","name":"customer_address","namespace":"customer_address.avro","fields":[{"name":"datetime","type":"long"},{"name":"ca_address_sk","tye":["null","long"]},{"name":"ca_address_id","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"ca_street_number","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"ca_street_name","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"ca_treet_type","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"ca_suite_number","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"ca_city","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"ca_county","type":["null","string"]},{"name:"ca_state","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"ca_zip","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"ca_country","type":["null","string"]},{"name":"ca_gmt_offset","type":["null","double"]},{"name":ca_location_type","type":["null","string"]}]}

```
field right now is :datetime type:LONG pos:0 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_address_sk type:UNION pos:1 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_address_id type:UNION pos:2 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_street_number type:UNION pos:3 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_street_name type:UNION pos:4 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_street_type type:UNION pos:5 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_suite_number type:UNION pos:6 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_city type:UNION pos:7 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_county type:UNION pos:8 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_state type:UNION pos:9 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_zip type:UNION pos:10 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_country type:UNION pos:11 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_gmt_offset type:UNION pos:12 the value in the generic record is null
field right now is :ca_location_type type:UNION pos:13 the value in the generic record is null

the values at index: 0 is `201812190510`
the values at index: 1 is `596508`
the values at index: 2 is `AAAAAAAAMBKBJAAA`
the values at index: 3 is 613
the values at index: 4 is 3rd
the values at index: 5 is Ln
the values at index: 6 is Suite 300
the values at index: 7 is Pleasant Hill
the values at index: 8 is Marion County
the values at index: 9 is OH
the values at index: 10 is 43604
the values at index: 11 is United States
the values at index: 12 is -5.0
the values at index: 13 is single family
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your code `"field right now is :"+ nextField+"` vs the output `field right now is :datetime type:LONG pos:0`, then you would see that it's calling `get("datetime type:LONG pos:0")`, which *should* return null, because that is not the same as calling `get("datetime")` for  just the field name.

Here is a workaround that combines both loops and access the values by the positions

```
for (int pos = 0; itr.hasNext(); pos++) {   
    String nextField = itr.next().toString();
    System.out.printf("field right now at pos:%d is :%s ; the value in the generic record is %s%n", 
        pos, nextField, genericRecord.get(pos));
    binaryObjBuilder.setField(nextField, genericRecord.get(nextField));
}
```

I'm not sure what `binaryObjBuilder` is expecting, but if you want to get/set by name, then I might suggest trying

```
String nextField = itr.next().toString();
String fieldname = nextField.split("\\s+")[0];
```

Comment: thank you, i figured it out. I should use String nextField = itr.next().name(); rather than toString. Will give the exact field name.